# I am trying to upgrade Grails 2.4 to 3.3.6 and fail to change environments: from Development to test. Can someone help me?

Tags: upgrade, grails-3.3.x

```
 if (Environment.current == Environment.TEST)
```

I am trying to upgrade Grails 2.4 to 3.3.6 and not able to change environments: from Development to test, Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the environment when your start the application.

```
grails -Dgrails.env=TEST run-app
```

Check [this](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#environments)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing only copy and paste my controllers and services so there is no run configuration was created by default. I just go to IntelliJ--Run--Edit configuration and added the information as per the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkCTN.png)